# How to edit the value displayed by [(ngModel)]?

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I am receiving a value, that I display to the user in a text field.

The idea is for him to be able to edit this value, and then send it back.

In the case of money, let's say I store the amount in cents, but I want to display it in dollars. Here is an idea of the code I have that display the value I receive :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myValue" value="{{myValue}}" />
```

I tried this without success :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myValue/100" value="{{myValue/100}}" />
```

How can I display that value divided by 100 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the desugared syntax of `[()]`.

```
<input type=text [(ngModel)]="myValue">
```

is equivalent to

```
<input type=text [ngModel]="myValue" (ngModelChange)="myValue = $event">
```

This means that you can separately control how do you want data to flow in, and how should events flow out.

Comment: Wonderful ! Thanks you.