# Cannot use ternary if statement inside [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

Trying to user ternary if statement inside ngModel.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="(mode == 'edit') ? userToUpdate.name_first : newUser.name_first" id="name_first" class="form-control" type="text">
```

Expression
(mode == 'edit') ? userToUpdate.name_first : newUser.name_first
binds model only for newUser.name_first, but doen't bind model to userToUpdate.name_first.

Here is the place where I've tried to use the statement: 
https://github.com/alex-chaliy/TeamManager/blob/master/client/src/app/home/home.component.html#L43

Comment: On what scenarios this condition will be executed

Comment: This seems like something that would be betters suited in the code, rather than the template.

Comment: ngModel accept only component field names, so you cannot pass expression that should be calculated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit the value displayed by \[(ngModel)\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45832439/how-to-edit-the-value-displayed-by-ngmodel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just fixed the problem using the 'userToWrite' variable for both modes.

Answer (score 2):

How is it supposed to work?? This expression does not make sense. When input value gets updated, how does Angular understand which value on model it should update? You should use getter/setter instead.

```
get firstName(): string {
    return (mode == 'edit') ? this.userToUpdate.name_first : this.newUser.name_first;
}
set firstName(val: string) {
    if(mode === 'edit') this.userToUpdate.name_first = val;
    else this.newUser.name_first = val;
}
```

PS. I don't really like the solution I gave to you, because the fact that your component should know whether the user is new or not tells me that the design is bad. You'd better take it as input parameter to your component from the component above and let that higher component pass either existing user object or a new empty one.